# Footer image printed twice when printing certificates in iText

Tags: itext

When we print certificate all most print in certificate but footer image is printing twice. I am using Pdfptable for printing footer image.

```
table = new PdfPTable(1);
int footerWidth[] = {100};
table.setWidths(footerWidth);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
Image image2 = Image.getInstance("footerImage.jpg");
cell = new PdfPCell(image2,true);
cell.setBorder(0);
table.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().width()-document.leftMargin()-document.rightMargin());
table.addCell(cell);
//write the footer
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(), table.getTotalHeight()+document.bottomMargin(), writer.getDirectContent());
EventLog.write(appName,"done adding footer",logFile);
document.add(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table is added twice because you add it twice.

You add it a first time when you use `writeSelectedRows()`:

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(), table.getTotalHeight()+document.bottomMargin(), writer.getDirectContent());
```

This adds the table at a very specific position defined by the coordinates:

```
x = document.leftMargin();
y = table.getTotalHeight()+document.bottomMargin();
```

You add the table a second time, when you do this:

```
document.add(table);
```

This adds the table at whichever position the page cursor is at, which is usually immediately after the previous content that was added with a `document.add()` method.

**PS:**

Headers and footers are usually added in an `OnEndPage()` page event. You're adding the footer only once. You may want to use page events to add the footer on every page.

Comment: If we will not write document.add(table). it will not print footer image

Comment: That is very hard to believe without proof.